# How to connect to DynamoDB on AWS using a Spring Boot application running on local system?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, microservices

I'm working on Spring Boot microservice REST based application and backedn database is currently local Dynamodb database. I can make REST calls using Postman to my application running locally and can perform CRUD operation with the local dynamodb database.
Now I want to make changes in the configuration so that whenever I make similar CRUD operations on my application running locally the data should be saved/updated on actual DynamoDB running on AWS & not local. Basically, I want to point application to remote DynamoDB endpoint. Is it possible? Is there any sample reference guide available to make such configuration changes?

Currently, this is my configuration class and properties file:-

```
package com.user.profile.jpa;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig;
import com.amazonaws.util.StringUtils;
import org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.config.EnableDynamoDBRepositories;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

//@Profile("dev")
@Configuration
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(basePackages = "com.user.profile.jpa")
public class DynamoDbConfig {

    @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.endpoint}")
    private String amazonDynamoDBEndpoint;

    @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.region}")
    private String amazonDynamoDBRegion;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.accesskey}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.secretkey}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(amazonAWSCredentials());

        if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(amazonDynamoDBEndpoint)) {
            dynamoDB.setEndpoint(amazonDynamoDBEndpoint);
        }

        return dynamoDB;
    }

    @Bean
    public AWSCredentials amazonAWSCredentials() {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    }
}



amazon.dynamodb.endpoint=http://localhost:8000/
amazon.aws.accesskey=JGDSGJSGS8729224
amazon.aws.secretkey=HJKAHDD83ERWRnHAHDJASD8782rlGb0F1k2Ijg
amazon.dynamodb.region="us-east-1"

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.profiles.active=dev

server.port=8090
```

Please assist. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the endpoint (leave empty for remote) and credentials/keys:

```
amazon.dynamodb.endpoint=[leave empty if using AWS, or http://localhost:[dynamodb port] if using local ]
amazon.aws.accesskey=[your AWS access key if using AWS or arbitrary text if using local]
amazon.aws.secretkey=[your AWS secret key if using AWS or arbitrary text if using local]
```

You have some examples here:
https://tech.smartling.com/getting-started-with-amazon-dynamodb-and-java-universal-language-850fa1c8a902

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the dynamoDB endpoint to the correct system, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html.

In your case it might be `dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

You might as well use the correct accessKey and secretAccessKey.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to DynamoDB on AWS from local system, use the below configuration. The below example connects to US_EAST_1 region. Replace with your aws region in which the DynamoDb is running.

```
@Configuration
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(basePackageClasses = YourRepository.class)
public class DynamoDBConfiguration {

    @Value("${aws.access.key}")
    private String awsAccessKey;
    
    @Value("${aws.secret.key}")
    private String awsSecretKey;

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider())
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
    }
    
    private AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider(){
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
               new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey));
    }

}
```

Add the below properties to your application.properties

```
aws.access.key = <YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY>
aws.secret.key = <YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY>
```

Note: The above code will only work if your IAM role have the permission to access the service using the above credentials.

If the microservice is to be deployed in the aws EC2 instance, then it is like to access the DynamoDB with in aws. In most of the cases it would be with in same aws account and same aws region. In that scenario you don't need to provide any details. Refer the Configuration class below. That is what you will need.

```
import org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.config.EnableDynamoDBRepositories;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.company.project.dao.YourRepository;

@Configuration
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(basePackageClasses = YourRepository.class)
public class DynamoDBConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
    }

}
```

But when the region changes, then you would have to pass the region value with in the configuration as shown below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(basePackageClasses = YourRepository.class)
public class DynamoDBConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
    }

}
```

Regarding the authorization, accessKey and secretKey won't be needed. The IAM role has to be configured at the EC2 end to access the DynamoDB instance.